# Как использовать ответ с anticaptcha для решения капчи в python

Tags: python

У меня есть вот такой код для решения HCaptcha с помощью AntiCaptcha.
В ответ я получаю разгаданную капчу, но что потом с этим ответом делать(если можно с применением webdriver)

```
ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = "6ef84e2806f59c112af2127abbdfbbb9dd72"
WEB_URL = url 
SITE_KEY = "2df90a06-8aca-45ee-8ba2-51e9a9113e82"

time.sleep(3)
print("Отправляю запрос на решение капчи")
result = HCaptchaTaskProxyless.HCaptchaTaskProxyless(anticaptcha_key=ANTICAPTCHA_KEY).captcha_handler(websiteURL=WEB_URL, websiteKey=SITE_KEY)

new_result = result["solution"]["gRecaptchaResponse"]
```

Comment: Ну можно на листочке напечатать на память, например.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [исходному коду](https://github.com/lorien/captcha_solver/blob/master/captcha_solver/solver.py#L90-L130) нужно создать объект класса *CaptchaSolver*, вызвать метод *solve_captcha*, на выход которому передать *data* с URL страницы с капчей и решенной капчей.